# Cancan: Multiple abilities with AND operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have the following statement in my user_ability.cs class

```
can :read, Bike, :product => {:created_by => user.id, :company_id => user.company_id }
```

But this pops up an error: **undefined "table_name" from Nil:class** due to following statement that is under "/cancan/lib/cancan/model_adapters/active_record_adapter.rb"

```
name = model_class.reflect_on_association(name).table_name.to_sym
```

Now if we change the ability code as follows, application runs but ***OR*** is applied to the executed query.

```
can :read, Bike, :product => {:created_by => user.id}
can :read, Bike, :product => {:company_id => user.company_id }
```

And we want **AND** condition to work between *created_by* and *company_id*

- Ruby version: 2.5.5p157
- Rails version: 4.2.11.1
- Cancan gem
  version: 1.6.10

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first statement. Are you sure `user` is being set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a scope as the third argument to `can`:

```
can :read, Bike, Bike.joins(:product).where(products: { created_by: user, company_id: user.company_id })
```

See [defining abilities](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities).

Comment: I would say you're butting up against the limitations of CanCanCan's DSL here though. When stuff starts getting even slightly complex it turns into a real mess. I abandoned it for Pundit years ago.